# Let K be a field, and $I=(XY,(X-Y)Z)⊆K[X,Y,Z]$. Prove that $√I=(XY,XZ,YZ)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $K$ be a field, and let $I=(XY,(X-Y)Z) \subset K[X,Y,Z]$. Prove that $\sqrt{I}=(XY,XZ,YZ)$.

I have no idea how to start with this question, can anybody give me some hint?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about starting by using the [Hilbert's_Nullstellensatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_Nullstellensatz)?

Comment: sounds a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will to use the following fact

> Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be elements of $ \mathbb{k}[x_1,\dots x_n]$. We have the following identity between radical ideals: $$\sqrt{(A,BC)}=\sqrt{(A,B)}\cap\sqrt{(A,C)}$$

In our case, using this useful fact, we obtain the decomposition $$\sqrt{(XY,(X-Y)Z)}=\sqrt{(X,(X-Y)Z)}\cap \sqrt{(Y,(X-Y)Z)}=
\sqrt{(X,YZ)}\cap \sqrt{(Y,XZ)}$$
In the same way we have 
$$\sqrt{(Y,XZ)}=\sqrt{(Y,Z)}\cap \sqrt{(Y,X)}$$
and
$$\sqrt{(X,YZ)}=\sqrt{(X,Z)}\cap \sqrt{(X,Y)}$$
Using this identities we obtain
$$\sqrt{(XY,(X-Y)Z)}=\sqrt{(X,Z)}\cap \sqrt{(X,Y)} \cap \sqrt{(Y,Z)}=(X,Y)\cap (X,Z)\cap(Y,Z)$$ 
as required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. just I am not sure about the identity between radical ideals: $$\sqrt{(A,BC)}=\sqrt{(A,B)}\cap\sqrt{(A,C)}$$ do you have some reference about this identity?

Comment: Think to the associated varieties...

Comment: More general: $$\sqrt{I+JK}=\sqrt{I+J}\cap\sqrt{I+K}$$ for any ideals $I,J,K$.

Comment: You haven't finished the problem. You showed $\sqrt{(XY,(X-Y)Z)}=(X,Y)\cap (X,Z)\cap(Y,Z)$. We want to show $\sqrt{(XY,(X-Y)Z)}=(XY)+ (XZ) +(YZ)$.

Comment: @AlJebr is easy to verify that $(XY, XZ, YZ)=(X,Y)\cap (X,Z)\cap (Y,Z)$ exactely in the same way, for example. Moreover, I think it is a classical fact about monomial ideals.